# find the intersection of two array structs in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

How can I find the following intersection of two array structs in Matlab.

For example, I have two struct arrays `a` and `b`:

```
a(1)=struct('x',1,'y',1);
a(2)=struct('x',3,'y',2);
a(3)=struct('x',4,'y',3);
a(4)=struct('x',5,'y',4);
a(5)=struct('x',1,'y',5);


b(1)=struct('x',1,'y',1);
b(2)=struct('x',3,'y',5);
```

I want to find the intersection of `a` and `b` as follows:

```
c = intersect(a,b)
```

where `c` should be

```
c = struct('x',1,'y',1);
```

But when it seems wrong when I type `intersect(a,b)` since the elements of `a` and `b` are both structures. How can I combat this difficulty. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elegant solution would have been to supply `intersect` with a comparator operator (like in , e.g., [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/)).
Unfortunaetly, Matlab does not seem to support this kind of functionality/flexibility.

A workaround for your problem would be

```
% convert structs into matrices
A = [[a(:).x];[a(:).y]]';
B = [[b(:).x];[b(:).y]]';
% intersect the equivalent representation
[C, ia, ib] = intersect( A, B, 'rows' );
% map back to original structs
c = a(ia);
```

Alternatively, have you considered replacing your structs with class objects derived from handle class? It might be possible to overload the [relational operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.relationaloperators.html) of the class and then it should be possible to sort the class objects directly (I haven't looked closely into this solution - it's just a proposal off the tip of my head).

Answer (score 4):

A more general variant of Shai's approach is:

```
A = cell2mat(permute(struct2cell(a), [3 1 2]));
B = cell2mat(permute(struct2cell(b), [3 1 2]));
[C, ia] = intersect(A, B, 'rows');
c = a(ia);
```

This way you don't need to explicitly specify all the struct fields. Of course, this won't work if the struct fields contain non-numeric values.

#### Generalized approach for fields of any type and dimensions

If you're uncertain about the type and size of the data stored in your structs, `interesect` won't cut it. Instead, you'll have to use `isequal` with a loop. I'm using `arrayfun` here for elegancy:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:numel(a), 1:numel(b));
c = a(any(arrayfun(@(m, n)isequal(a(m), b(n)), X, Y)));
```

Comment: the solutino is only valid if all fields are numeric scalars.

Comment: @Shai Numeric, yes, but not necessarily scalars (as long as `cell2mat` succeeds). That's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: if they are not scalars they must all be of the same size. Anyhow, +1 for the generalization.

Comment: @Shai I did further generalization with `isequal` :)

Answer (score 1):

A systematic approach would be to produce a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) - and then use intersect:

```
hash_fun = @(x) sprintf('x:%g;y:%g',x.x,x.y);

ha = arrayfun(hash_fun,a,'UniformOutput',false);
hb = arrayfun(hash_fun,b,'UniformOutput',false);

[hi,ind_a,ind_b]=intersect(ha,hb)
res=a(ind_a) % result of intersection
```

Comment: oh - I didn't realize. What criteria for hash functions did I overlook?

Comment: It should have a fixed length.

Comment: ah - I see. so a `%16g` instead of %g would make it a hash then.

Comment: Technically yes. But the idea is no different from Shai's answer -- only instead of converting the fields into vectors of numerical values, you're converting them into strings (arrays of chars). In both implementations one still has to manually specify the names of the fields one by one. Also, your current implementation fails when the fields contain matrices instead of scalars.

Comment: I didn't mean to say the other answers are bad. Just wanted to point out another way of putting it. It might be helpful if the struct at one point would contain strings or whatever. btw it would be easy to write a function that would not need you to specify the names of fields using `fieldnames` - or even abusing `disp` might be possible - but in this case it would be an overkill.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to come off judgmental :) I was just trying to point out that both solutions have a flaw of not handling non-scalar fields, and they're current implementations can become a bit cumbersome when there are a lot of fields.

Comment: Never mind :) I'm just experimenting with hashing in one of my projects. Tried to give a simplest example. For more complex cases it IMHO would make sense to use some library. Personally I would loop over property fields and use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html (though didn't test it properly :)

Comment: How would you hash matrices?

Comment: The hash code builder I linked can work with double arrays. So I would just use this function.